# Pandas Set Data Type While Combining Files

Tags: python, pandas

I used below codes to combine a bunch of csv files. There is a column `[UPC]` start with `000000`. Pandas detect the UPC as numeric value so all leading zeroes are ignored.

```
import pandas as pd
file_ptn = os.path.join('nielsen_sku_fact*.csv')
files = glob.glob(file_ptn)
sch_inx = [
        '[All Markets]',
        '[All Periods]',
        '[UPC]'
        ]
df = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(left,right), [pd.read_csv(f,index_col=sch_inx) for f in files])
```

The challenge is that `[UPC]` needs to be set as index in order to combine all files into the same schema. I prefer to use `combine_first` method for code elegance purposes; so no need to suggest a different merge/combine method other than `combine_first`.

Comment: Do you need `pd.read_csv(f,index_col=sch_inx, dtype={sch_inx:str})` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is with the index_col paramter, why not set the index after reading the csv. i.e

```
li = [pd.read_csv(f, dtype={d:object for d in sch_inx }).set_index(sch_inx)  for f in files] 

main_df = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(left,right),li)
```

Lets take an example for preserving the leading zeroes i.e

```
    amount  donorID  recipientID  year
0     0100      101           11  2014
1     0200      101           11  2014
2     0500      101           21  2014
3     0200      102           21  2014
# Copy the above dataframe 

sch_ind = ['amount','donorID']
df = pd.read_clipboard(dtype={d:object for d in sch_ind}).set_index(sch_ind)

print(df)
                recipientID  year
amount donorID                   
0100   101               11  2014
0200   101               11  2014
0500   101               21  2014
0200   102               21  2014
```

If it works with `clipboard` it works with `csv` too.

Comment: Hmmm, fo you think `.set_index(sch_inx)` should working?

Comment: I tried with `read_clipboard` and it worked so might work with `csv` as well

Comment: Hmmm, for me it failed :(

Comment: @jezrael check the edit, I dont understand how it failed. OP wanted leading zeroes in index right.

Comment: OK, there is MultiIndex, ya, I think OP need something else.

Comment: Let the answer stay. For some reason OP might be after this. Let me wait for OP's reply

Comment: I modified your answer a bit to make it one-liner. `df = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(left,right), [pd.read_csv(f,dtype={'[UPC]': 'str'}).set_index(sch_inx) for f in files])`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need change `combine_first` and add parameter `dtype` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) by dictionary - column name with type `str`.

Also for index is used [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) for intersection between columns names and `sch_inx` and select intersected column(s):

```
dfs = []
di = {d:str for d in sch_inx}
for fp in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, dtype=di)
    #if want only first intersectioned column add [0]
    #col = np.intersect1d(df.columns, sch_inx)[0]
    col = np.intersect1d(df.columns, sch_inx)
    dfs.append(df.set_index(col))

df = reduce(lambda left,right: left.combine_first(right), dfs)
```

You cannot use `dtype` with `index_col` in pandas `0.22.0`, because [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9435).

Comment: also `dtype={sch_inx:object}` for preserving the dtype. Much like str.

Comment: @Dark - hmmm, never used it, do you have experience with it?

Comment: I tried just `dtype={'[UPC]': 'str'}` and it didn't work. I guess it's due to the challenge that `[UPC]` is part of the index.

Comment: @jezrael since `sch_inx` is a list perhaps there is a need for a dict compehension, I thought it was a string

Comment: You might simply define a short helper function to import each individual dataframe, specifying the dtypes for each column, setting the index, then returning the parsed dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael the edited answer won't work thats the reason I used `set_index`

Comment: @jezrael are you sure? I tried in kaggle too, it doesn't work

Comment: @Dark - sure ;) I test it with glob and files.

Comment: @jezrael take a look. https://www.kaggle.com/bharathsh/checking-the-index-col-parameter/ index is still `int` rather than `str` index_col wont convert the dtypes I think. More probably a bug .

Comment: Yes I thought so, `set_index` is the fix. Even Jezz have suggested the same

Answer (score 2):

**Point 1**
There are several ways to preserve the string-ness of the `'[UPC]'` column.

1. Use `dtype` as mentioned in other posts
2. Use [**`converters`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
3. Perform the conversion afterwards with `pd.Series.str.zfill`

---

**Setup**
Let's begin by setting up some files.  I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I can use the handy `%%writefile` magic.

```
%%writefile nielson_sku_fact01.csv
[All Markets],[All Periods],[UPC],A,B
1,2,0001,3,4
1,3,2000,7,8
```

---

```
%%writefile nielson_sku_fact02.csv
[All Markets],[All Periods],[UPC],C,D
1,4,0001,3,4
1,3,3000,7,8
```

---

```
%%writefile nielson_sku_fact03.csv
[All Markets],[All Periods],[UPC],B,D
1,4,0002,10,11
1,2,2000,8,8
```

Let's use OP's code to get some vars

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

files = glob.glob('nielson_sku_fact*.csv')
sch_inx = [
    '[All Markets]',
    '[All Periods]',
    '[UPC]'
]
```

Now let's show how the three conversions work:

1. `pd.read_csv('nielson_sku_fact01.csv', dtype={'[UPC]': str})`

   ```
      [All Markets]  [All Periods] [UPC]  A  B
   0              1              2  0001  3  4
   1              1              3  2000  7  8
   ```
2. `pd.read_csv('nielson_sku_fact01.csv', converters={'[UPC]': str})`

   ```
      [All Markets]  [All Periods] [UPC]  A  B
   0              1              2  0001  3  4
   1              1              3  2000  7  8
   ```
3. Using `pd.Series.str.zfill`

   ```
   pd.read_csv('nielson_sku_fact01.csv')['[UPC]'].astype(str).pipe(
       lambda s: s.str.zfill(s.str.len().max()))

      [All Markets]  [All Periods] [UPC]  A  B
   0              1              2  0001  3  4
   1              1              3  2000  7  8
   ```

---

**Point 2**
If you want elegance, There is no need to use a lambda that takes two arguments when `pd.DataFrame.combine_first` is already a function that takes two arguments.  In addition, you can use `map` with a prepared reading function to make it nice and clean:

```
def read(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        converters={'[UPC]': str}
    ).set_index(sch_inx)

reduce(pd.DataFrame.combine_first, map(read, files))

                                     A     B    C     D
[All Markets] [All Periods] [UPC]                      
1             2             0001   3.0   4.0  NaN   NaN
                            2000   NaN   8.0  NaN   8.0
              3             2000   7.0   8.0  NaN   NaN
                            3000   NaN   NaN  7.0   8.0
              4             0001   NaN   NaN  3.0   4.0
                            0002   NaN  10.0  NaN  11.0
```

---

**Point 3**
I think you should reconsider using `pd.DataFrame.combine_first` because the nature of `glob` doesn't look like you can control the order of your files very easily.  And you might get unpredictable outcomes depending on how `glob` returns those files.  Unless you don't care, then... good luck.

Comment: Hi @Dark I don't know what those standards are.  I'm likely going to focus on providing clear and detailed content.  I've had my fun with FGITW before.  It doesn't interest me as much anymore.

Comment: `providing clearer and detailed content along with improved code` that's the standard. I never knew reduce can be done this clean without lambda. Your answer is great as always.

Comment: Thank you, you are kind as always.

Answer (score 0):

When using `read_csv`, you can set the type of a column by passing a `dtype` argument. Eg:

```
pd.read_csv(f, index_col=sch_inx, dtype={'[UPC]': 'str'})
```

See: [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I know the syntax. However, the challenge is `[UPC]` is part of the index so `dtype={'[UPC]': 'str'}` didn't work.